# How to take screenshot of a DOM node with overflow:auto in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a main part of an application in Chrome Dev Tools, which is wrapped in a UI with top navigation and a sidebar. Slack, Gmail and many others work like that.

When I open Dev Tools, find the `div` that holds the main content area and invoke **Capture node screenshot**, I only get the visible part of it: for example, what I currently see in Slack, not the entire loaded history of a channel.

It's probably connected to `overflow:auto` as I can't even take a screenshot of a very small paragraph here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Examples

Is that a limitation of Dev Tools? Is there a trick of how to take the screenshot of such nodes? I'm especially interested in Slack or Gmail scenarios where the nodes typically have thousands of pixels vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome implemented it in v89: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2021/01/devtools#node-screenshot